# CakePHP - Retrieving and working with data from different tables

Tags: cakephp

I'm sorry, I am a newbie in CakePHP and I am a little bit confused in this subject, let me explain:

I have a relationship between two tables. One of the table is Dose and the other is tank. So, one Tank belongs to a Dose. A Dose has many Tanks. The table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE `doses` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `dose` INT(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

In my Tank view I have the following code:

```
<?php echo $form->input('dose_id', array('class'=>'input', 'label' => ''));?>
```

Each 'dose' (field) from Dose table correspond to a value, such as 200, 300, and so forth. I need to use these numbers to calculate others numbers before to insert into my database (table tank). For instance, my code in tanks_controllers:

```
$t_u = $this->data['Tank']['tipo_uso_id'];
if( $t_u == '1'){
$this->data['Tank']['producao_adubo_diaria'] = $this->data['Tank']['dose_id'] * 0.10;
.
.
.
```

However, it is bringing to me the ID of the Dose and not the value (dose field). Where can I set up this to bring me the correct data (dose)? I tried to set up this way in my model:

```
'Dose' => array(
        'className' => 'Dose',
        'foreignKey' => 'dose_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => 'dose',
        'order' => ''
    )
```

It did not work.

I appreciate your time helping me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`it is bringing to me the ID of the Dose and not the value (dose field). Where can I set up this to bring me the correct data (dose)?`

You need to get it from the db (model), not from the view. So you need to do a find(). If you are new to Cake, you should read the cookbook first to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

What does `$form->input('dose_id')` produce? A dropdown? If so; by default cake will produce a dropdown with the `value` containing `(dose_)id`, and the text you see as the value of `$displayField`(usually name/title).

To do this; if I understand you, you would need to first query `doses` for all the values and store the result in an array using the `dose` value as the key AND the value, rather than the `id` as you normally would. You would then be able to access the actual dose value from `$this->data`.

```
$doseArray=array();
$doses = $this->Dose->find('all');
foreach($doses['Dose'] as $k => $v) {
    $doseArray[$v] = $v;
}
```

perhaps. Seems a bit redundant so I might be off.